# Can I apply forEach in aggregate query in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a member collection and find members by specific conditions and after get members I need to do some calculation for each member. To calculate need query on the same collection.

My process is

```
var eachMemberInfo = [];
var members = db.collection('member').find({ createdDate: currentDate, country: 'BD'}).toArray();
members.forEach(function(doc) {
  var result = db.collection('member').aggregate([
    { $match: { memberType: doc.memberType, country : doc.country } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {memberType:"$memberType",country:"$country"},
        memberCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$gt: ["$numberOfInvitees",0]},1,0]} },
        lessCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$and:[{$lt:["$numberOfInvitees", doc.numberOfInvitees]}, {$gt: ["$numberOfInvitees",0]}]},1,0]} },
        sameCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$eq: ["$numberOfInvitees",doc.numberOfInvitees]},1,0]} }
      }
    }
  ]).toArray();

   eachMemberInfo.push({memberId:doc.memberId,memberCount: result[0].memberCount, lessCount: result[0].lessCount});

});
```

**My question is how can I do this using single aggregate query?**

can any one help me pls :)

**For example:**

**member** collection like:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8c06"),
    "memberID" : 80,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 2,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8c09"),
    "memberID" : 81,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 3,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8fgh"),
    "memberID" : 82,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 4,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8cfgd"),
    "memberID" : 83,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 1,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8cfgd"),
    "memberID" : 84,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 2,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD"
}
..............
]
```

Expected result in **eachMemberInfo** like:

```
[
  { memberID : 80, memberCount:5,lessCount: 1,sameCount:2 },
  { memberID : 81, memberCount:5,lessCount: 3,sameCount:1 },
  { memberID : 82, memberCount:5,lessCount: 4,sameCount:1 },
  { memberID : 83, memberCount:5,lessCount: 0,sameCount:1 },
  { memberID : 84, memberCount:5,lessCount: 1,sameCount:2 }
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that with the aggregation pipeline. You should understand that MongoDB aggregation is a series of special operators applied to a collection. When you execute an aggregation pipeline, MongoDB pipes operators into each other i.e. the output of an operator becomes the input of the following operator. The result of each operator is a new collection of documents.

Hence what you are trying to achieve in the above can be simply rewritten as the following pipeline without the need to create an array of documents first:

```
var collection = db.collection('member'), 
    pipeline = [
        { "$match": { createdDate: currentDate, country: 'BD' } },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": { "memberType": "$memberType", "country": "$country" },
                "memberCount": { 
                    "$sum": { "$cond":[ { "$gt": ["$numberOfInvitees", 0] }, 1, 0 ] } 
                },
                "sameCount": { "$sum": 1 } 
            }
        }
    ];

collection.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

Follow-up to the changes to your question, running the following aggregation pipeline will give you the desired result:

```
var collection = db.collection('member'), 
    pipeline = [   
        { "$match": { createdDate: currentDate, country: 'BD' } },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": { 
                    "memberType": "$memberType", 
                    "country": "$country" 
                },            
                "invitees":{ 
                    "$push":  {
                        "memberID": "$memberID",
                        "count": "$numberOfInvitees"
                    }
                },
                "inviteesList": { "$push": "$numberOfInvitees" },
                "memberCount": { "$sum": 1 } 
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$invitees" },
        { "$unwind": "$inviteesList" },
        { 
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$invitees.memberID",
                "sameInviteesCount": { 
                     "$sum": { 
                        "$cond": [ 
                            { "$eq": ["$inviteesList", "$invitees.count"] }, 
                            1, 0 
                        ] 
                    }
                },
                "lessInviteesCount": { 
                    "$sum": { 
                        "$cond":[ 
                            { "$lt": ["$inviteesList", "$invitees.count"] }, 
                            1, 0 
                        ] 
                    }
                },
                "memberCount": { "$first": "$memberCount" }
            }
        }
    ];

collection.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your relay @chridam and if we want to calculate this `lessCount:`  how can I apply ? updated my question

Comment: your query return single object with `_id, memberCount, sameCount` but I need `memberCount, sameCount` for each member

Comment: I posted another question related this question. can you help me pls @chirdam  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502794/is-possible-foreach-and-multiple-aggregation-for-each-document-using-aggregation

Comment: If we add `skip` and `limit` to find **members** what will change in query? like: `var members = db.collection('member').find({ createdDate: currentDate, country: 'BD'}).skip(size).limit(1000).toArray();` but my **aggregate** query has no change  @chridam

Comment: @shaishabroy To add skip and limit to your aggregate query, use the [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit) and [`skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/#pipe._S_skip) pipeline operators. Not sure how your results will pen out since you have the data hand, why don't you give that a go and see how that fares?

Comment: if I add `skip` and `limit` then query return wrong result. say if I use  `{"$sort":{"_id":1}},{"$skip":0},{"$limit":3},` it return result for id=80 is `{ memberID : 80, memberCount:3,lessCount: 0,sameCount:1 },` because of  for member 80 only compare and count among 80,81 and 83  but I need compare for member 80 with all members like 80,81,82,83,84 then it will give exact result. Result should be same as previous.

Comment: Then that's a separate question you need to ask else you risk changing the existing question into a [**chameleon question**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions/), which I'm sure you are aware it's deemed bad practice here on SO.

Comment: posted another question @chridam http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520773/can-i-apply-foreach-in-aggregate-query-with-skip-and-limit-in-mongodb