# Is possible forEach and multiple aggregation for each document using aggregation in MongDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a member collection and find members by specific conditions and after get members I need to do some calculation for each member. To calculate need query on the same collection.

```
var eachMemberInfo = [];
var members = db.collection('member').find({ createdDate: currentDate, country: 'BD'})
             .skip(skipSize).limit(1000).toArray();
members.forEach(function(doc) {
  /* =================calculate resultRatingCW for each member=================*/
  var resultRatingCW = db.collection('member').aggregate([
    { $match: { memberType: doc.memberType, country : doc.country,createdDate: currentDate } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {memberType:"$memberType",country:"$country"},
        memberCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$gt: ["$numberOfInvitees",0]},1,0]} },
        lessCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$and:[{$lt:["$numberOfInvitees", doc.numberOfInvitees]}, {$gt: ["$numberOfInvitees",0]}]},1,0]} },
        sameCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$eq: ["$numberOfInvitees",doc.numberOfInvitees]},1,0]} }
      }
    },
    {$project: { ratingCW: { $multiply: [{$divide: [{$sum: ["$lessCount", {$multiply: ["$sameCount", 0.5]}]}, "$memberCount"]}, 100]}, _id:1}}
  ]).toArray();

  /* =================calculate resultRatingWW for each member=================*/
  var resultRatingWW = db.collection('member').aggregate([
    { $match: { memberType: doc.memberType,createdDate: currentDate } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {memberType:"$memberType"},
        memberCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$gt: ["$numberOfInvitees",0]},1,0]} },
        lessCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$and:[{$lt:["$numberOfInvitees", doc.numberOfInvitees]}, {$gt: ["$numberOfInvitees",0]}]},1,0]} },
        sameCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$eq: ["$numberOfInvitees",doc.numberOfInvitees]},1,0]} }
      }
    },
    {$project: { ratingWW: { $multiply: [{$divide: [{$sum: ["$lessCount", {$multiply: ["$sameCount", 0.5]}]}, "$memberCount"]}, 100]}, _id:1}}
  ]).toArray();
  /* =================calculate resultIncoCW for each member=================*/
  var resultIncoCW = db.collection('member').aggregate([
    { $match: { memberType: doc.memberType, country : doc.country, createdDate: currentDate } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {memberType:"$memberType",country:"$country"},
        memberCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$gt: ["$memberTotalDistLocCurrency",0]},1,0]} },
        lessCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$and:[{$lt:["$memberTotalDistLocCurrency", doc.memberTotalDistLocCurrency]}, {$gt: ["$memberTotalDistLocCurrency",0]}]},1,0]} },
        sameCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$eq: ["$memberTotalDistLocCurrency",doc.memberTotalDistLocCurrency]},1,0]} }
      }
    },
    {$project: { incoCW: { $multiply: [{$divide: [{$sum: ["$lessCount", {$multiply: ["$sameCount", 0.5]}]}, "$memberCount"]}, 100]}, _id:1}}
  ]).toArray();

  /* =========calculate resultIncoWW for each member=================*/
  var resultIncoWW = db.collection('member').aggregate([
    { $match: { memberType: doc.memberType, country : doc.country, createdDate: currentDate } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {memberType:"$memberType"},
        memberCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$gt: ["$memberTotalDistUSD",0]},1,0]} },
        lessCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$and:[{$lt:["$memberTotalDistUSD", doc.memberTotalDistUSD]}, {$gt: ["$memberTotalDistUSD",0]}]},1,0]} },
        sameCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$eq: ["$memberTotalDistUSD",doc.memberTotalDistUSD]},1,0]} }
      }
    },
    {$project: { incoWW: { $multiply: [{$divide: [{$sum: ["$lessCount", {$multiply: ["$sameCount", 0.5]}]}, "$memberCount"]}, 100]}, _id:1}}
  ]).toArray();



  eachMemberInfo.push(
    {
    memberId:doc.memberId, 
      RatingCW: resultRatingWW[0].ratingCW, 
      resultRatingWW: resultRatingWW[0].ratingWW,
      resultIncoCW: resultIncoCW[0].incoCW,
      resultIncoWW: resultIncoWW[0].incoWW
    });

});
```

**My question is, Is it possible using single aggregate query?**

**Or any best solution ?**

can any one help me pls :)

**For example:**

**member** collection like:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8c06"),
    "memberID" : 80,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 2,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD",
    "memberTotalDistUSD": 2,
    "memberTotalDistLocCurrency": 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8c09"),
    "memberID" : 81,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 3,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD",
    "memberTotalDistUSD": 3,
    "memberTotalDistLocCurrency": 3
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8fgh"),
    "memberID" : 82,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 4,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD",
    "memberTotalDistUSD": 4,
    "memberTotalDistLocCurrency": 4
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8cfgd"),
    "memberID" : 83,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 1,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD"
    "memberTotalDistUSD": 1,
    "memberTotalDistLocCurrency": 1
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8cfgd"),
    "memberID" : 84,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 2,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD",
    "memberTotalDistUSD": 2,
    "memberTotalDistLocCurrency": 2
}
..............
]
```

Expected result in **eachMemberInfo** like:

```
[
{ memberID : 80, RatingCW:4,ratingWW: 4, incoCW:4, incoWW:3},
{ memberID : 81, RatingCW:4.5,ratingWW: 4.5, incoCW:4.5, incoWW:2.5 },
{ memberID : 82, RatingCW:5,ratingWW: 5, incoCW:5, incoWW:5 },
{ memberID : 83, RatingCW:3,ratingWW: 3, incoCW:3, incoWW:3 },
{ memberID : 84, RatingCW:4.5,ratingWW: .5, incoCW:4.5, incoWW:4.5 }
]
```

**NB: result value is dummy but want this format**

Comment: Again, it would be really helpful if you could add some sample documents and your expected output for that dataset. Just out of interest, how is the above not different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496419/can-i-apply-foreach-in-aggregate-query-in-mongodb ?

Comment: you can use `$and` but i dont think it will solve the purpose as looking by your code, you are storing the outcome of each query into a separate variable, so it may no be useful for you.  As mentioned by @chridam if you can share the expected output, we may help!

Comment: added an example @chridam and AjitejKaushik