# Can I apply forEach in aggregate query with skip and limit in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a member collection and find members by specific conditions and after get members I need to do some calculation for each member. To calculate need query on the same collection.

My process is

```
var eachMemberInfo = [];
var members = db.collection('member').find({ createdDate: currentDate, country: 'BD'}).skip(skipZize).limit(limitSize).toArray();
members.forEach(function(doc) {
  var result = db.collection('member').aggregate([
    { $match: { memberType: doc.memberType, country : doc.country } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {memberType:"$memberType",country:"$country"},
        memberCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$gt: ["$numberOfInvitees",0]},1,0]} },
        lessCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$and:[{$lt:["$numberOfInvitees", doc.numberOfInvitees]}, {$gt: ["$numberOfInvitees",0]}]},1,0]} },
        sameCount: { $sum: {$cond:[{$eq: ["$numberOfInvitees",doc.numberOfInvitees]},1,0]} }
      }
    }
  ]).toArray();

   eachMemberInfo.push({memberId:doc.memberId,memberCount: result[0].memberCount, lessCount: result[0].lessCount});

});
```

**My question is how can I do this using single aggregate query?**

can any one help me pls :)

**For example:**

**member** collection like:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8c06"),
    "memberID" : 80,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 2,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8c09"),
    "memberID" : 81,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 3,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8fgh"),
    "memberID" : 82,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 4,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8cfgd"),
    "memberID" : 83,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 1,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57905b2ca644ec06142a8cfgd"),
    "memberID" : 84,
    "memberType" : "N",
    "numberOfInvitees" : 2,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "BD"
}
..............
]
```

Expected result in **eachMemberInfo** like:

```
[
  { memberID : 80, memberCount:5,lessCount: 1,sameCount:2 },
  { memberID : 81, memberCount:5,lessCount: 3,sameCount:1 },
  { memberID : 82, memberCount:5,lessCount: 4,sameCount:1 },
  { memberID : 83, memberCount:5,lessCount: 0,sameCount:1 },
  { memberID : 84, memberCount:5,lessCount: 1,sameCount:2 }
]
```

Without using `skip` `limit` got expected result but if I add skip and limit then query return wrong result. say if I use `{"$sort":{"_id":1}},{"$skip":0},{"$limit":3},` it return result for **id=80** is `{ memberID : 80, memberCount:3,lessCount: 0,sameCount:1 },` because of for member *80* only compare and count among *80,81 and 83* but I need compare for member *80* with all members like *80,81,82,83,84* then it will give exact result. Result should be same as previous.

without using `skip` and `limit` i used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496419/can-i-apply-foreach-in-aggregate-query-in-mongodb) solution

Comment: because of I have huge amount of record. If I don't use `skip` and `limit` got out of memory exception

Comment: sorry, I didn't saw your full code. I delete my comment. Anyway, I struggle to understand what you want to do.

Comment: it's ok no problem

Comment: I think you are doing something fishy..  Are you applying an aggregation forEach member of the result?   Can you explain better what exactly what you want to do, and, how your data looks, i.e. it contains more document having the same memberID ?

Comment: I gave an example with this question and can see this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496419/can-i-apply-foreach-in-aggregate-query-in-mongodb

Comment: And why you did not correct your aggregation code according to that answer?  You can ignore your first query, move it as a match stage in the pipeline, in the end of the aggregation pipeline you can apply skip, limit and sort.

Comment: I mentioned that what solution I used without `skip` and `limit`